# Using Jinja2 with Django, load tag does not work

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, jinja2

I'm building a Django app and chose to use Jinja2 for my templating engine. I noticed after I switched from Django's built in templating engine to Jinja2 the `load` keyword would not work, ex: `{% load static %}`. This is used to load static files like CSS. Is there a Jinja workaround for this in Django?

> TemplateSyntaxError at /app/
>   Encountered unknown tag 'load'.

From settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/templates/jinja2'),
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'environment': 'my_project.jinja2.environment',
    },
},
```

Django: 1.11
Jinja2: 2.9.6

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should work. What's your templates settings inside `settings.py`?

Comment: I updated with my settings from `settings.py`. Getting `unknown tag` error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is explained in the manual section for [Jinja2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2) in django template reference

> The default configuration is purposefully kept to a minimum. If a
>   template is rendered with a request (e.g. when using render()), the
>   Jinja2 backend adds the globals request, csrf_input, and csrf_token to
>   the context. Apart from that, this backend doesn’t create a
>   Django-flavored environment. It doesn’t know about Django filters and
>   tags. In order to use Django-specific APIs, you must configure them
>   into the environment.

Yes, {% load static %} does not exists, but there is a simple work around. Again, the example is from the reference

```
from __future__ import absolute_import  # Python 2 only

from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.urls import reverse

from jinja2 import Environment


def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'static': staticfiles_storage.url,
        'url': reverse,
    })
    return env
```

Comment: This makes sense, I did set up a `jinja2.py` with the above. I removed `{% load static %}` and formatted as `{{ static 'app/style.css' }}` and it works. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is expected behavior in Jinja2. That is because with Jinja2 tags are not loaded from the template page, but extensions are added to the Jinja2 env during the creation. When it starts running (and the env is created), you cannot add more extensions.

You can see more info regarding this here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/extensions/#adding-extensions