# How do I access static files using Jinja in Django

Tags: django, jinja2, static-files

I am using Jinja templating within Django and I am having trouble getting static files to load.  I have tried setting up the back end per this documentation (I've included the code below): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2

However, I am getting an "Encountered unknown tag 'static'" if I include a `{% load static 'path' %}` tag.  If I include a `{% load static %}` tag, I get "Encountered unknown tag 'load'." error.

I have setup a "jinja2.py" file in the main folder with the following code:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.urls import reverse

from jinja2 import Environment


def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'static': staticfiles_storage.url,
        'url': reverse,
    })
    return env
```

settings.py has the following code:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django_jinja.backend.Jinja2",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "environment": 'valuation.jinja2.environment',
        }
    },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The code in the base template is:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Valuation App</title>

        <!--Bootstrap icons-->
        <link href="{% static 'assets/fonts/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--Google web fonts-->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Mono:ital@0;1&family=Open+Sans:wght@300..800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Rounded:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
    <!--Simplebar css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/vendor/css/simplebar.min.css' %}">
    <!--Choices css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/vendor/css/choices.min.css' %}">

    <!--Date range picker-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/vendor/css/daterangepicker.css' %}">
    <!--Main style-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/style.min.css' %}">
  </head>
```

Any guidance is very much appreciated.

See above code for what I tried.

Comment: Could you show the template code where you encounter mentioned errors?

Comment: I've added the code in the base.jinja template.  I've tried with and without the {% load static %} tag.

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271949/using-jinja2-with-django-load-tag-does-not-work) which links to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2) describing this specific case (scroll to the end).

Comment: Hi Ivan.  Thank you for your guidance.  I had the template syntax incorrect.  The template needed to use the following syntax: {{ static('path_to_file') }}.  Thank you again.